# Adjustment of header placement in fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr

I'm using the **fancyhdr** package with the book class, and I need to not only lengthen the header to be wider than `\textwidth` (e.g., using `\fancyheadoffset`) but also to control its position.

[EDITED TO REPLACE IMAGE WITH MWE]

For example, the following sample shows that I have section titles that start well to the left of the main text. I would like to extend the header so that its left edge aligns with the section number while preserving the alignment with the text on the right edge.  And I need this to work for both odd and even pages.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[calcwidth]{titlesec}

\setlength{\textwidth}{5.0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1.5in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{1.5in}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\Large\bfseries}{\hspace*{-1in}\thesection}{1em}{}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{{\it #1}}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[CO]{\rightmark}


\begin{document}
\section{Section One}
\kant[1]
\section{Section Two}
\kant[2]
\section{Section Three}
\kant[3]
\section{Section Four}
\kant[4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You already know that command. You just say e.g. `\fancyheadoffset[leh,roh]{15pt}` and, if your document is using a two-sided layout, it will all be applied appropriately. (You may want `[loh,reh]` of course, as your offset seems to be opposite from mine, but it is the same idea.

Comment: But that's not a command to specify the 'precise position on the page' by any stretch of the imagination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want the command to have inner/outer-sensitive offset, you just add the options to `\fancyhoffset`. For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyheadoffset[loh,reh]{20mm}
% \fancyheadoffset[leh,roh]{20mm}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[loh,reh]{Left Odd Right Even}
\fancyhf[leh,roh]{Left Even Right Odd}
\fancyhf[cf]{\thepage}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \kant[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image: Way One]

Replacing

```
\fancyheadoffset[loh,reh]{20mm}
% \fancyheadoffset[leh,roh]{20mm}
```

with

```
% \fancyheadoffset[loh,reh]{20mm}
\fancyheadoffset[leh,roh]{20mm}
```

flips the effect:

[image: Way Two]

## EDIT

Since you want the offset always on the left of the page, it is even easier (if a bit odd for a book):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[calcwidth]{titlesec}

% Note that setting these manually is not at all wise use e.g. geometry instead
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1.5in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{1.5in}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\Large\bfseries}{\hspace*{-1in}\thesection}{1em}{}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{{\itshape #1}}}% \it ought not be used with LaTeX 2e!!
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[CO]{\rightmark}
\fancyheadoffset[lh]{25.4mm}

\begin{document}
\section{Section One}
\kant[1]
\section{Section Two}
\kant[2]
\section{Section Three}
\kant[3]
\section{Section Four}
\kant[4-8]

\end{document}
```

[image: keep to the left]

Comment: I was not aware of the options to \fancyheadoffset.  Based on the above example, I found that

\fancyheadoffset[leh,loh]{1in}

achieved the desired effect.

Comment: @GrantPetty I just edited using your code. You can just say `[lh]` since you want the same for both odd and even pages. I used metric, but that's not compulsory ;).

Comment: I couldn't find any reference to the 'h' option in the documentation.  What does it do?

Comment: `[lh]` for left header, regardless whether even or odd. `[rh]` for right header. I don't think I used a `[h]` but, if I did and you point it out, I'll correct it.

Comment: I had seen options 'le', 're' 'ro' etc., no 'rh' or 'lh'.  Apparently I haven't found the definitive documentation for fancyhdr.